# SQL Server : set all privileges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-grant

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . 
TO 'abc'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY '*' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This query is in Mysql and I want the SQL Server version of this query. I tried all ways including online converter (the online converter simply copy paste the code not converting) but no results. If anybody know please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+grant+privileges

Answer (score 0):

from [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
GRANT ALL ON dbo.YourTable TO abc WITH GRANT OPTION
```